# Count Distinct on Converted and Concatenated Columns and Grouping by Each Record

Tags: t-sql

```
select
 distinct convert(varchar(8), Creative.Width) + 'x' + convert(varchar(8), Creative.Height) as FormatName 
 from Creative 
 where CreativeFileDate > '1 SEP 18'
```

Query pulls the unique records as my per my concatenation. How do I most efficiently find the counts of each now?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use group by and count

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_count_avg_sum.asp

My SQL is a bit rusty, but your query should look something like:

```
select convert(varchar(8), Creative.Width) + 'x' + convert(varchar(8), Creative.Height) as FormatName, count(0)
 from Creative 
 where CreativeFileDate > '1 SEP 18'
group by convert(varchar(8), Creative.Width) + 'x' + convert(varchar(8), Creative.Height)
```

Cheers